# Анимация перехода между активити

Tags: android

Всем привет.В андроиде я новичок,да и по Java самоучка :)Пишу игру типа РПГ,чисто практики ради. У меня есть 2 активити со стандартной анимацией перехода между ними(листание). Хочу сделать не листания,а например аля что бы при переходе с 1-ой активити на 2-ю, вторая активити "из не от куда" розворачивалась на весь экран,перекрывая собой 1-ую активность.Может есть уже готовые статьи?В интернете адекватного материала я найти не смог,что бы тот описывал от и до данный процесс.Есть ли в андроид студио какие то готовые анимации и инструкции по их применению?Буду очень благодарен за обширный и развёрнутый ответ. Спасибо зарание!

Comment: а чем не нравится описание в документации https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity?

Comment: Спасибо за документацию , прочту на кануне. Я просто искал инфу ,мне не было понятно что к чему конкретно.Спасибо )